# When I move my mouse on ubuntu VM, mouse cursor disappears and reappears when i stop moving. How can I to fix it?

Tags: mouse, windows-10, vmware

I have created an Ubuntu VM with VMware on my Windows 10 laptop. When I move the mouse cursor in Ubuntu, it is just disappearing and reappearing when i stop
Plus I reinstalled everything, and it's still happening .. Help anyone?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

i must say im no VM or Linux expert 
but i struggled with this for some time

i found the only solution was to run VMware in admin elevation on Win host

un-elevated = no mouse cursor .... mouse work but no cursor visible

elevated = mouse cursor .... all good